# Laravel on GAE slow response times

Tags: php, google-app-engine, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5.2 with [GaeSupportL5](https://github.com/shpasser/GaeSupportL5) package on Google App Engine and we are seeing some slow response times. ~700ms TTFB for pages not hitting the database compared to ~70ms on a standard VPS.

We are using memcache to cache services, config, routes and compiled views files.

Are these normal response times for this kind of setup?

Comment: To try and identify where the bottleneck is, you can look in the response logs for your application. There will be a field like "ms=" that will tell you how long it took the backend to process your request. How close is that number to 700ms?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: No, I gave up on using Laravel with GAE for the time being. 
I did get a response from a google engineer, that they wouldn't be surprised with the response times compared to the raw VPS.

Comment: have the same experience... still looking for a solution